# IOS share extension to launch parent app as chrome extension does

Tags: ios, swift, ios-extensions

Looking to find a solution where I can launch parent app using IOS extension, some says it's not possible but chrome extension does it. Like clicking a url and opening it into my app.

Comment: Sounds like a universal link.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/allowing-apps-and-websites-to-link-to-your-content

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app

Make sure you pay close attention to security as noted in BOLD RED.

Comment: It's like I have created a browser app. And when user visiting a link in safari I want my app to be displayed along with chrome in share icons

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I don't have chrome. Do you mean you're in safari and you tap the little square with the arrow button?

Comment: exactly, that bottom sheet that pops up

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/app_extension_support/supporting_suggestions_in_your_app_s_share_extension

Comment: Is that what you're looking for?